# technisch vs fachlich (sch vs ch)

Tags: adjective, spelling, suffix

Ganz knappe Frage: Gibt es einen Grund, dass man "technisch" mit "sch" am Ende schreibt, "fachlich" aber mit "ch"?

Das ist mir gestern beim Chatten aufgefallen, als ich beide Wörter in einem Satz genutzt habe und am Ende "fachlich" zu "fachlisch" korrigiert habe, weil ich mir bei "technisch" ziemlich sicher war, dass man es eben mit "sch" schreibt.

Comment: Man schreibt es, wie man es spricht, und `fachlisch` wäre falsch ausgesprochen.

Comment: @knut Nicht überall. Ich kann zum Beispiel kein /ç/ aussprechen, oder zumindest muss ich mich sehr genau auf die Aussprache konzentrieren um nicht in das - für mich übliche - /ʃ/ zu verfallen.

Comment: @knut Genau wie bei Em1 ist es bei uns hier auch. "ch" und "sch" sprechen wir hier eigentlich alle nur wie "sch". Etwas bewusst mit "ch" auszusprechen klingt für mich immer fremd.

Comment: Man merkt das ich aus dem Süden komme ;) Ich kann sogar [Chuchichäschtli](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuchichäschtli) aussprechen.

Comment: @knut Aus dem Süden komme ich auch, wohl aus dem anderen. ;)

Comment: Dazu sag ich nur: "Gechichte"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Auch wenn es die Frage nicht komplett beantwortet: Die beiden Wörter unterscheiden sich in ihrer Herkunft; und das **könnte** in diesem Fall (Adjektivbildung, Wahl des Suffixes) relevant sein.

- [Technik](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technik)<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup> ist eine [neoklassische Wortbildung](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Neoklassisch/Intro.html?MenuId=WordFormation112)<sup>[canoo]</sup> aus dem griechischen τεχνικός (technikós) bzw. τέχνη (téchne). Bei diesen Wörtern kommen verschiedene [Suffixe für die Adjektivbildung](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Neoklassisch/Adjektiv/Suffig.html?country=D)<sup>[canoo]</sup> in Frage, darunter [*-isch*](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/isch.html)<sup>[canoo]</sup>, aber nicht *-lich*.
- [Fach](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fach)<sup>[Duden]</sup> kommt wohl aus dem Mittel- / Althochdeutschen, hat also keine "klassischen" Wurzeln. Hier kann das häufigere [*-lich*](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/lich.html?country=D)<sup>[canoo]</sup> zum Zuge kommen.

Ob die Erklärung "zwingend" ist, kann ich nicht sicher sagen. Aber ich fand es auffällig, dass *-isch* explizit [im Zusammenhang mit der Suffigierung neoklassischer Formative genannt](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/isch.html#Anchor-Neoklassisches-47857)<sup>[canoo]</sup> wird, *-lich* hingegen nicht.

Comment: +1 für "Suffigierung neoklassischer Formative". Ich möchte versuchen, das in meinen aktiven Wortschatz zu übernehmen.

Answer (score 2):

Hier spielen die Grenzen zwischen den Wortbestandteilen eine Rolle, es geht also eher um Etymologie als Orthografie:

- Technik -> technisch: Hier kommt nur ein "-sch" dazu (eigentlich ein
  "-isch", wie bei "kindisch", "weibisch", etc. Das "-i-" verschwindet)
- Fach -> fachlich: Hier kommt ein "-lich" dazu (wie bei "gelblich",
  "handwerklich", etc.)

Es gibt zwar ein paar vage [Daumenregeln](http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/adjektive-auf--i--ig-isch-lich--i-), welche Endung wann verwendet wird, aber das sind wirklich nur grobe Anhaltspunkte (wie meistens bei solchen etymologischen Fragen).

Comment: Ich sehe den Erklärungsgehalt nicht. Du beschreibst nur empirisch, dass bei Technik ein `isch` dazukäme. Was hindert uns bei `fach` ebenfalls ein `isch` anzuhängen? Was ist die fachische Erklärung?

Comment: Erklärung im Sinne von "übertragbare Regel" habe ich auch keine anzubieten - welches Suffix verwendet wird, hängt m.E. primär davon ab, was sich im jeweiligen Fall eingebürgert hat. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass ein auf Latein oder Griechisch basiertes Wort auf "-isch" endet, ist zugegebenermaßen hoch. Einen echten Hinderungsgrund, dass sich nicht auch beim nicht-klassischen "Fach" "fachisch" hätte einbürgern können, sehe ich nicht, außer vielleicht, dass es eben eine der bevorzugteren Endungen ist. Ist halt so gelaufen, oder?